# MySQL Count with Join and Group

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have been struggling for a couple of hours on a query, but just can't get it right.  Two tables, one for students, and a second that contains all of the classes for which each student has registered.  I need a result set that has one row per student, plus the count of classes for which the student has registered.  Here's my closest attempt to date:

```
SELECT 
count(*), student.*
FROM student 
LEFT JOIN schedule
ON student.id = schedule.studentid
GROUP BY schedule.studentid
```

I am using LEFT JOIN because the results must include students that have not yet registered for any classes.  The tables are being joined by the student id, which is also how I am grouping them.

The current rendition seems to be working (mostly), except it's not returning students without any classes in their schedule.

I'm quite stuck here, and looking for anyone that can give me a quick push out of the mud.  Thanks for any traction you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close :-)

```
SELECT 
    student.*, count(*)
FROM student 
    LEFT JOIN schedule ON student.id = schedule.studentid
GROUP BY student.*
```

should work fine

Comment: I receive a syntax error with group by student.*, but the query appears to work as expected with group by student.id.  Thanks for the quick and excellent example!

Comment: yeah, well then instead of student.* just show and group the columns one per one

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding how about a subquery:

```
SELECT 
     *, (select count(sch.id) from schedule as sch where sch.studentid = stu.id) as ClassNum
FROM student as stu
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) `count` FROM schedule s where s.studentid=student.id) `count` FROM student
```